# Presale contract - Cant send tokens to the contract

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, presale

I have created a token and a presale contract on remix.

User should be able to send BNB to the presale contract and receive the token in their wallet, but when i try to send funds to PRESALE contract address the send button is grayed out.

TOKEN - 0x041c187f2E7E836992E0cA5783EB6d28089C3683

PRESALE - 0x34001ba089B3FA600FC478C74fC43A1689D00153

You can see the contract codes using BSC scan as both contracts are verified.

```
     // Function to participate in the presale
        function participate() external payable {
            require(block.timestamp >= presaleStartTime, "Presale has not started");
            require(block.timestamp <= presaleEndTime, "Presale has ended");
            require(msg.value > 0, "Must send BNB to participate");
    
            uint256 tokensPurchased = msg.value.mul(presaleRate);
            require(tokensPurchased > 0, "Insufficient BNB sent");
    
            // Check if the presale cap is reached
            require(getPresaleRaised() + msg.value <= presaleCap, "Presale cap reached");
    
            // Transfer tokens to the contributor
            IERC20(daddyDogeToken).transfer(msg.sender, tokensPurchased);
    
            // Update contribution mapping
            contributions[msg.sender] = contributions[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
    
            // Emit event
            emit Con

tribution(msg.sender, msg.value, tokensPurchased);
    }
```

This is the participate function within the presale.

Comment: If a button is greyed out, this either seems like a frontend issue or about some condition in the contracts. Very difficult to know what the real issue is. You don't say anything about where and how you try to access the functionality. Also please provide the relevant part of the contract here.

Comment: I have added the participate function from the presale contract.

Comment: You only answered about one fourth of my questions. "Button being greyed out" doesn't really give us any information.